# Uploading KML file from android to the map feed (My places on server)

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

Does anybody know how to upload local KML file from android to Google account "My places".

I create KML file from my application and save it to sd card. Then I want to upload it to users Google account places.

I couldn't find it in Android Maps API. Maybe it coud be via HTTP Protocol.

Thank you,
Toni

Comment: You mentioned that you created KML file from your Android application, can you share any link or something that you followed to do this?

Comment: Hi @Vignesh. I'm just appending data (coordinates, etc.) to txt file. I prepare data according to kml standard (see [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently an API for My Places.

Comment: Hi. I know there is no official API, but I saw one android application that offers direct upload of google maps overlays to the map feed, but I forgot the name of the app :(. Thank you anyway for the replay.